# HTML/Javascript: How to control refresh action without re-submit the form

Tags: javascript, html

We are trying to implement a web page that each time of page refreshing will not result in the form resubmit, how to achieve that? Is there any Javascript code or HTML can make it WITHOUT external javascript library(jquery, dojo or extJs)

The reason of such design is that the form is going to tie an unique relation to current data with means cannot do it twice but for security reason we have to use POST instead of GET, also after the action we still want to preserve user the right to do similar action on the same page to another relation. so how to avoid a consequence like that?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code.  We aren't going to give you a solution when you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @Daedalus Thank you. To be honest I haven't try anything practically because I don't have an idea. I hope to have an idea as a solution even no code is provided that I can manage to implement. I only can think about is redirect to current page after finish the action from post..but not sure that could be the best solution. Could you give a hint? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the action to the form submits it to `submit_form.php`. That file can handle the data and do whatever it needs to do. Then in it's response, it can redirect the browser to a separate page (you'll have to look up the exact method of how to do this depending on what language you write your POST handler in). This separate page can show the results of the form submit using session variables or some other method.

Comment: Thanks, seems the Post/Redirect/Get is the best way to go